# How to set milliseconds in a timestamp created by seconds-to-time?

Tags: time-date, format-time-string

I have a milliseconds-since-epoch value such as `1698089051778` that I want to convert to a human readable string.

I use `(seconds-to-time (/ ms-since-apoch 1000))` to convert from string to timestamp and `(format-time-string "-- %Y-%m-%d %T.%3N" ...)` to format but that loses the milliseconds value.

Is there a function similar to `seconds-to-time` that converts milliseconds? Is there a way to set the milliseconds in the `timestamp` object so I can use `%3N`?

I guess I can omit `.%3N` in the format string and add it to the final string but I would prefer to keep it in the timestamp object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the time functions, it is that you are using integer division, so you lose the fractional part. Try:

```el
(seconds-to-time (/ ms-since-epoch 1000.0))
```

and leave everything else as is (untested, but it feels right :-) ).

Comment: The problem was that I assumed `seconds-to-time` needs an integer, which is why I was forcing integer divison :)